# MySql workbench is installed but not opening

Tags: mysql, installation, workbench

I have installed mySql server two days ago on windows 8.1. It was working fine but now all of a sudden it is not opening.Task Manager shows that it is running but it does not open. Any solution?

Comment: first upgrade your computer to windows 10 second see in the logs if there is a problem listed, also event viewer is also a good start

Comment: @nbk it does not work on windows 8?

Comment: I don't know, windows 8 was bad and so i never used it. but when all other tips doesn't work, it is a sensible step

Comment: Is it workbench that won't open? Your post is not clear to me if you are talking about mysql or workbench.

Comment: @honeyboy Wilson mysql workbench does not open... I am able to access mysql commandline

Comment: Did you use task manager to end the workbench process and then try starting it? Or have you tried rebooting your pc?

Comment: Yes I have tried. It shows a message that says something like not suitable operating system

Answer (score 1):

After I updated mysql workbench, it stopped working.

This solution worked for me:

Delete the **Workbench** file in `%APPDATA%\MySQL\Workbench` and it should work. After deleting it, Mysql workbench will create these files again and should open. It worked for me. **But!** it will delete any unsaved scripts and custom configurations.